# Export Xcode build warnings

Tags: xcode, devops

I want to collect all of the build warnings that Xcode generates into a data file that I can pass to other tools. I've tried parsing the output of xcodebuild and that *kinda* works.

The problem is that the logs are very messy. Ideally warnings look like this

```
/Users/me/proj/myapp/RequestLayerFramework/Request Sender/RequestSender.h:370:74: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
- (void)createAndExecuteRequestWithHref:(NSString *)zoneHref
                                                  ^
                                                  _Nullable
```

But sometimes for no apparent reason they look like this

```
/Users/me/proj/myapp/Reques
tLayerFramework/Request Sender/RequestSender.h:
370
:
74
: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be nu
ll

- (void)createAndExecuteRequestWithHref:(NSString *)zoneHref

                                                  ^
                                                  _Nullable
```

I've really tried to make this work, but I keep finding weird corner cases that confuse my parser. It's too fragile.

Is there a build setting or something that makes these warnings easily collectible? I want file, line, column, and message for each warning.

Comment: I talked to an Apple engineer about this and it stumped him. He thought it was possible to export some kind of report, but after searching for it they couldn't find anything.